# How to implement Logout in ASP.NET Core MVC using OpenID and redirecting user to another sign-in page

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect, okta

I am trying to set up ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application's logout functionality and looks like I'm not able to sign out user successfully. I should be able to have user navigate to a custom dashboard page where user would re-enter new credentials after successful signout of the previous session. Please assist in correcting the code attached. Thank you

```
AddOpenIdConnect(oidcOptions =>
   {
       oidcOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       oidcOptions.Authority = configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:Domain");
       oidcOptions.ClientId = configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:ClientId");
       oidcOptions.ClientSecret = configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:ClientSecret");

       oidcOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
       oidcOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
       oidcOptions.Scope.Add("email");

       oidcOptions.SaveTokens = true;
       oidcOptions.UseTokenLifetime = true;
       oidcOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
       oidcOptions.UsePkce = true;

       oidcOptions.SignedOutRedirectUri = configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:SignOutRedirectUri");

       oidcOptions.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
       {
            OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx =>
            {
               ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:RedirectUri");

               return Task.CompletedTask;              
            },

            OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async ctx =>
            {
               ctx.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:SignOutRedirectUri");
               await Task.CompletedTask;
            },          
            OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = context =>
            {
                context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:PostLogoutRedirectUri");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
      };
   });

"Okta": {
    "ClientId": "1A993j2wHzXomRJ6gvsdOc297",
    "ClientSecret": "V2c23523gftBY6ep-ILwfsdrm_oa6c0n2jt8JMU",
    "Domain": https://login-qa.abc/oauth2/default,
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri":https://localhost:45515/signout-oidc,
    "RedirectUri": https://localhost:45515/signin-oidc,
    "SignOutRedirectUri": https://qa.my.abc/
}

[Authorize]
public IActionResult Logout()
{
    return SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                      OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

Comment: What's your SignOut() method

Comment: [Authorize]
public IActionResult Logout()
{
    return SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                      OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}